# Track User ID in dimension in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have store UserName as UserId like:
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX', { @if (Request.IsAuthenticated){@Html.Raw("'userId': '" + User.Identity.Name + "'");} });

in my asp.net mvc website: 
[www.persiangulfcup.org](http://www.persiangulfcup.org)

But I can't monitor specific username and track his/her actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two very important things to note here:

1) User ID **must not** contain any personally identifiable information. So in your case, using the person's name is a violation of the terms of use and you may risk having your account shut down:

> It is up to you to provide the ID. These IDs typically come from an authentication system, in which each signed-in user account has a stable, and unique ID with which it is associated, and should have the following characteristics:
>
> 1. Non-personally identifiable
> 2. Unique to a user of your service or app
> 3. Persistent for a signed-in user across all devices

2. User ID cannot be queried in the API or web interface:

> The User ID value can not be queried as a dimension in reports in either the web interface or the APIs.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id

If you want to run queries based on the User ID, you'll have to create a custom dimension and set that to the same value as the User ID.

Comment: Thank you for answer, **The User.Identity.Name** is not personal info and is a **Integer number** that I converted to String. Please tell me more about how to use UserId as custom dimension and then see them

Comment: You can read about custom dimensions here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829